# Why celery should use subtask instead of task directly inner another task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am writing workflow using celery,  But I can't understand term 'subtask'. for example:

```
@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    add.delay(1, 2)
    return x + y
```

Task 'add'  could execute correctly.

```
@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    subtask(add).delay(1, 2)
    return x + y
```

so, why we should subtask? someone can help me? THX

Comment: It's actually pretty well described in the docs: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#canvas-designing-workflows